# Scifi short story that is only dictionary entries, including a word for eating maternal grandmothers

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember a scifi short story that was comprised entirely of dictionary entries, leaving the reader to speculate about the kind of alien culture that required these terms. A lot of the entries dealt with lineage, parents and grandparents, and the proper way to eat the corpse of your maternal grandmother, if I remember correctly.

I also vaguely recall, but I might be wrong, that there was a follow-up story in the same anthology with additional entries.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think this is [Confluence](https://books.google.com/books?id=cQhke8K9G60C&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=brian%20aldiss%20confluence&source=bl&ots=fhCMphydVm&sig=K4ohuQ2yvvSqJ1isWrl6DipHl-0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLo4zKwIPaAhXEw6YKHdfgA5gQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=brian%20aldiss%20confluence&f=false) by Brian Aldiss.
The story is according to the link, a partial glossary/dictionary of the language of the alien Myrinians.  This was published in 1967 in Punch magazine

There was also a sequel to this story title [Confluence Revisited](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2064781.Other_Edens_2) from an Other Edens collection (1988)

> "Confluence Revisited" by Brian Aldiss, a sequel to his 1967 alien dictionary piece "Confluence",

An extract from the review on Goodreads gave me the start on the original story

Haven't found the whole story yet to confirm the quote in the OP but this seems to fit the style.

[image]

Comment: That's probably it "CA PATA VATUZ - the taste of a maternal grandfather" etc.  If they read it in the Merril anthology SF 12, there's "Primary Education of the Camiroi" in there too, which is another list-based story.